# Minecraft 1.5.2 - Extend reach

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I want to extend my reach in minecraft, but I have tried almost every mod, and nothing is working. I am using 1.5.2.

Just to be clear, I do not have a server, this is single player.

Is the best course of action simply to downgrade to a different minecraft version?

Comment: What do you mean by downgrade?

Comment: @LTPro: change the minecraft verison

Comment: Maybe you should update your minecraft, /reach should be in newer versions of spc.

Comment: I think it's time to close this question. Community keeps bumping it, since it was a good question at the time, but as outdated as it is, I highly doubt it's useful to anyone any more.

Answer (score 0):

There are many mods which can allow you to do this. Just get the Single Player Commands mod and use the `/reach` command to set your reach distance.

Comment: That has not been added to 1.5.2

Comment: @AriPorad Yes it has...

Comment: @Unionhawk, `/reach` -> `Command Not Found, Try /help for a list of commands`, `//reach` -> `Command Not Found, Try /help for a list of commands`, `/spc` works though

Comment: @AriPorad Ah... I thought you meant the mod itself. Huh. I could have sworn that has been in for a while.

Comment: No Problem, But is there a way to still get extended reach, it's driving me crazy

Comment: @Unionhawk Also, see update question